# How does R pass a variable from one object to a function without returning it?

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R-programming and have been struggling to understand how certain objects seem to pass variables to functions, but don't seem to return these variables overtly. Have a look at this example:

```
install.packages("cluster")
library(cluster)
x <- rbind(cbind(rnorm(10, 0, 0.5), rnorm(10, 0, 0.5)),
       cbind(rnorm(15, 5, 0.5), rnorm(15, 5, 0.5)),
       cbind(rnorm( 3,3.2,0.5), rnorm( 3,3.2,0.5)))
fannyx <- cluster::fanny(x, 2)
p <- cluster::clusplot(fannyx)
```

When examining the plot, the following information is provided:

`These two components explain 100 % of the point variability`

I simply don't understand where how this information is passed! The variability explained is not returned by the `fannyx`-object.

I've encountered this issue before when other functions have provided more information by `summary()` than by using `print()`.

How can this be explained?

Comment: Try just typing `fannyx` or `str(fannyx)` into the console. You'll see that `fannyx` is a list of 11 objects, ranging from the clustering parameters, to summary info, to coefficients. `clusplot` is extracting certain elements from the `fannyx` object to make the plot, and print summary info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we expand the `clusplot` function

```
cluster:::clusplot.default
```

We can see the line of code:

```
sub = paste("These two components explain", 
        round(100 * var.dec, digits = 2), "% of the point variability.")
```

So in this case this particular metric is calculated internally within the function, and then added to the plot.

**Edit:**

And we can see that `cluster:::mkCheckX` returns `var.dec`, which is called in `clusplot`

Comment: I`ve attempted to trace the calculation of `var.dec` within the package, but if I'm not mistaken, the information overtly returned by `cluster::fanny()` appears not to be sufficient

Comment: Check out the `mkCheckX` function called in the beginning of `clusplot`: `cluster:::mkCheckX`, it returns `var.dec`